# Multiple time frames based off current time frame

Tags: pine-script

Trying to set multiple timeframes to chart using the current timeframe as the base.  Goal was to go twice current and half current.  ie if I was in an hour chart my timeframes would the 2h/1h/and 30min and if I was in the 4hour my time frames would be 8h/4h/and 2h.  Just trying to have it automatically change instead of changing them manually.  any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This code is taken from our FAQ [here](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-define-a-higher-interval-that-is-a-multiple-of-the-current-one):

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Multiple of current TF")

resMult = input(2, minval = 1)

// Returns a multiple of current TF as a string usable with "security()".
f_MultipleOfRes( _mult) => 
    // Convert target timeframe in minutes.
    _TargetResInMin = timeframe.multiplier * _mult * (
      timeframe.isseconds   ? 1. / 60. :
      timeframe.isminutes   ? 1. :
      timeframe.isdaily     ? 1440. :
      timeframe.isweekly    ? 7. * 24. * 60. :
      timeframe.ismonthly   ? 30.417 * 24. * 60. : na)
      // Find best way to express the TF.
    _TargetResInMin     <= 0.0417       ? "1S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.167        ? "5S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.376        ? "15S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.751        ? "30S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 1440         ? tostring(round(_TargetResInMin)) :
      tostring(round(min(_TargetResInMin / 1440, 365))) + "D"

myRsi = rsi(close, 14)
plot(myRsi, color = color.silver)
// No repainting
myRsiHtf = security(syminfo.tickerid, f_MultipleOfRes(resMult), myRsi[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(myRsiHtf, color = color.green)
// Repainting
myRsiHtf2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, f_MultipleOfRes(resMult), myRsi)
plot(myRsiHtf2, color = color.red)
```