# Multiple timeframes based on current trouble (bis & tris)

Tags: pine-script

I'm doing a table which indicate for 7 higher timeframes if price is above or below EMA. Actually It seem it function properly, I can insert every timeframe by the input tab and obviously, if I watch an higher chart timeframe table keep itself static, with the problem that I've used the "request.security" and not the security for "lower timeframes", so data results a little wrong. So I'm trying to improve it keeping in the first row the current resolution, using as description "str.tostring(timeframe.period)" and since here all ok. The problem is that I should like that automatically the next row show me the 6 subsequents timeframes at the current one. I've just watched here the question [multiple time frames based on current time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536560/multiple-time-frames-based-off-current-time-frame) and I've read the pinecoders [FAQ](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-define-a-higher-interval-that-is-a-multiple-of-the-current-one), but, using the code, I'm not able to go further the the second row of the table which show me the subsequent timeframe automatically, I miss them for the others, also because I'm beginner. I attach 2 images of the table in 2 different resolutions.

[table in M1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmSKH.jpg)

[table in M3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nJRT.jpg)

```
// AUTOMATIC MULTIPLE OF CURRENT TIMEFRAME 
// ————— Converts current "timeframe.multiplier" plus the TF into minutes of type float.
f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60. :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.       :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 1440.    :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 10080.   :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 43800.   : na)
// Returns a multiple of current TF as a string usable with "security()".
f_MultipleOfRes( _mult) => 
    // Convert target timeframe in minutes.
    _TargetResInMin = timeframe.multiplier * _mult * (
      timeframe.isseconds   ? 1. / 60. :
      timeframe.isminutes   ? 1. :
      timeframe.isdaily     ? 1440. :
      timeframe.isweekly    ? 7. * 24. * 60. :
      timeframe.ismonthly   ? 30.417 * 24. * 60. : na)
      // Find best way to express the TF.
    _TargetResInMin     <= 0.0417       ? "1S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.167        ? "5S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.376        ? "15S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.751        ? "30S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 1440         ? str.tostring(math.round(_TargetResInMin)) : 
      str.tostring(math.round(math.min(_TargetResInMin / 1440, 365))) + "D"
// ————— Given current resolution, returns next step of HTF.
f_resNextStep(_res) =>
    // _res: current TF in fractional minutes.
    _res    <= 1        ? "3"  :
      _res  <= 3        ? "5"  :
      _res  <= 5        ? "15" :
      _res  <= 15       ? "30"  :
      _res  <= 30       ? "45"  :
      _res  <= 45       ? "60"  :
      _res  <= 60       ? "120"  : 
      _res  <= 120      ? "180"  : 
      _res  <= 180      ? "240"  : "1440"
// ————— Returns a multiple of current resolution as a string in "timeframe.period" format usable with "security()".
//f_multipleOfRes(_res, _mult) => ""


tf1_tab = "" // tf1_tab is the 1st timeframe of the table, that it's the current
vResInMinutes = f_resInMinutes() 
tf2_tab =   f_resNextStep (vResInMinutes) // the 2nd timeframe is automatically the next of the current
tf3_tab =   f_resNextStep (vResInMinutes) // the 3th timeframe is wrong because is the same of the 2nd
// tf5_tab = ??? how can I specify here for the other ???
// tf6_tab = ???
// tf7_tab = ???
```

Here a portion of code, that I've copied from the FAQ and tried to modify.

I also tried with the function " _fMultipleOfRes " but it seems don't function as I want because, as I seen, if I write "2" in the multiplier value, it return me the 2M timeframe, that not exist in the chart, the same problem trying as follow:

```
curr_tmf = timeframe.multiplier
tf1_tab = "" 
tf2_tab = curr_tmf + 2
tf3_tab = curr_tmf + 3
```

because if I'm in a 5M chart, it returns me timeframes M7 and M8 and not M15 and M30, as I'll want.
I'm near to solution but I miss the knowledge...
Someone can help me please?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you've already done all the hard work :)

You can get the next timeframe, by using your `f_resNextStep` function with the previous timeframe as an argument. Keep in mind that since the parameter is an `int` and the timeframe is a `string` you'll need to convert it using `str.tonumber()` function:

```
vResInMinutes = f_resInMinutes() 
tf2_tab = f_resNextStep(vResInMinutes)
tf3_tab = f_resNextStep(str.tonumber(tf2_tab))
tf4_tab = f_resNextStep(str.tonumber(tf3_tab))
tf5_tab = f_resNextStep(str.tonumber(tf4_tab))
tf6_tab = f_resNextStep(str.tonumber(tf5_tab))
tf7_tab = f_resNextStep(str.tonumber(tf6_tab))
```

Comment: wow wow wow! works as I hoped and dreamed it would! thank you very much, really! and sorry for my spaghetti-english! ;)